# How do I split a string with multiple word delimiters in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, split, delimiter

I want an efficient way to split a list of strings using a list of words as the delimiters. The output is another list of strings.

I tried multiple `.split` in a single line, which does not work because the first `.split` returns a list and succeeding `.split` require a string.

Here is the input:

```py
words = ["hello my name is jolloopp", "my jolloopp name is hello"]
splitters = ['my', 'is']
```

I want the output to be

```
final_list = ["hello ", " name ", " jolloopp", " jolloopp name ", " hello"]
```

Note the spaces.

It is also possible to have something like

```
draft_list = [["hello ", " name ", " jolloopp"], [" jolloopp name ", " hello"]]
```

which can be flattened using something like numpy `reshape(-1,1)` to get `final_list`, but the ideal case is

```
ideal_list = ["hello", "name", "jolloopp", "jolloopp name", "hello"]
```

where the spaces have been stripped, which is similar to using `.strip()`.

EDIT 1:

Using `re.split` doesn't fully work if the word delimiters are part of other words.

```
words = ["hellois my name is myjolloopp", "my isjolloopp name is myhello"]
splitters = ['my', 'is']
```

then the output would be

```
['hello', '', 'name', '', 'jolloopp', '', 'jolloopp name', '', 'hello']
```

when it should be

```
['hellois', 'name', 'myjolloopp', 'isjolloopp name', 'myhello']
```

This is a known issue with solutions using `re.split`.

EDIT 2:

```
[x.strip() for x in re.split(' | '.join(splitters), ''.join(words))]
```

does not work properly when the input is

```
words = ["hello world", "hello my name is jolloopp", "my jolloopp name is hello"]
```

The output becomes

```
['hello worldhello', 'name', 'jolloopp', 'jolloopp name', 'hello']
```

when the output should be

```
['hello world', 'hello', 'name', 'jolloopp', 'jolloopp name', 'hello']
```

Comment: I am confused. You say "note the spaces", which sounds like "I really want those spaces", but then, in the "ideal case" there are no spaces.

Comment: @tobias_k you are right. I just added the different possible outputs for extra info. The ideal output is the best output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `re` like,

Updated using the better way suggested by @pault using word boundaries `\b` instead of `:space:`,

```
>>> import re
>>> words = ['hello world', 'hello my name is jolloopp', 'my jolloopp name is hello']

# Iterate over the list of words and then use the `re` to split the strings,
>>> [z for y in (re.split('|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in splitters), word) for word in words) for z in y]
['hello world', 'hello ', ' name ', ' jolloopp', '', ' jolloopp name ', ' hello']
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I've thought of this and this solution doesn't work if the word delimiters are part of other words, as in
```
words = ["hellois my name is myjolloopp", "my isjolloopp name is myhello"]
splitters = ['my', 'is']
```
then the output would be
```
['hello', '', 'name', '', 'jolloopp', '', 'jolloopp name', '', 'hello']
```
when it should be
```
['hellois', 'name', 'myjolloopp', 'isjolloopp name', 'myhello']
```
This is a known issue with solutions using `re.split`.

Comment: @hansolo wouldn't it be better use word boundaries `\b` instead of forcing a space?

Comment: @hansolo Wow! Great! Thanks!

Comment: @hansolo Still, `\b` would be better. You can strip the spaces afterwards. Also note that with `" | ".join` (or `"\b|\b".join`) the space or `\b` might only be on one side, i.e. `"my | is"`instead of `" my | is "`. Better use `"|".join(f"\b{s}\b" for s in splitters)` or something like that.

Comment: Ha, seems like you made that edit 1 minute before I wrote that comment! About `f`-strings: point taken, but by that reasoning you could never use any new language features.

Comment: @hansolo New problem occurs when a string in the list does not contain any of the word delimiters. It will be joined to other words because of `''.join()`.

Comment: @hansolo The output is `['hello worldhello', 'name', 'jolloopp', 'jolloopp name', 'hello']` when it should be `['hello world', 'hello', 'name', 'jolloopp', 'jolloopp name', 'hello']`. This is becomes of `''.join()`. It joins all the strings in the list and then splits based on the regex. However, the strings in the list should not be joined in the first place. I have updated my question. Much appreciated.